# Не кликабельна кнопка в IE 10 , win 7

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-7, explorer

На главной  странице есть круг со стрелкой, вот картинка: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hprq1fqv4pgf5sp/Screenshot%202016-04-22%2017.08.00.png?dl=0

Во всех браузерах он кликабелен, только не в IE, в моем случие IE10. Помогите, кто знает в чем может быть проблема. Сайт: vuzum.com

Comment: выложите картинку, используя комбинацию клавиш Ctrl+G при редактировании вопроса, чтобы её можно было видеть без внешних ссылок. и выложите ваш код, который не работает, т.к. только по картинке никто гадать не будет